# Are there any issues with reassigning arguments as they're passed to a function

Tags: javascript

In the following `throttle` function, `timeout` eventually turns into a number as it's assigned to the setTimeout. I'm redefining it as `false` as it's cleared, the code works.

I don't notice anything on the surface, but wondering if there are any issues with doing things this way or there's something I might be missing?

```
const throttle = (fn, delay) => {
  let timeout;

  return (...args) => {

    if(!timeout) { 
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        fn(...args);
        clearTimeout(timeout = false);
      }, delay);
    }

  }
};
```

Comment: what is a throttle function?

Comment: This is safe to use, but not very readable.

Comment: Basically, it prevents a function from being executed unless the delay time has passed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code:

```js
clearTimeout(timeout = false)
```

is evaluated as:

```js
timeout = false;
clearTimeout(timeout)
```

which means you call `clearTimeout(false)` and this is not correct. `clearTimeout()` should be called with a timeout ID returned by `setTimeout()`.

It seems it works because you call `clearTimeout()` from the function that executes when the timeout expires. The call to `clearTimeout()` does not work but the timeout already expired and JavaScript clears it anyway.

Calling `clearTimeout()` from the timeout callback is not needed and does not help. The purpose of `clearTimeout()` is to call it before the timeout expires, to prevent the execution of the callback set with `setTimeout()`.

Your code should be:

```js
      timeout = setTimeout(() => {
        fn(...args);
        timeout = false;
      }, delay);
```

Comment: Oh, duh, can't believe I didn't notice the clearTimeout was being called after the timeout has already ended.. Yes, you're right, I used `timeout = false` instead of `clearTimeout(timeout = false)` and it still works, and the code is a bit cleaner.